# How to correct: SyntaxError: Named export 'mongo' not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to run a simple script to create a user with mongoose using nodejs. So basically just running `node my_script.js` which is the official way as per [Run Node.js scripts from the command line](https://nodejs.dev/learn/run-nodejs-scripts-from-the-command-line)

I have tried importing in the following ways:

```
import Connection from 'mongoose';
const { mongo } = Connection;
```

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
```

```
import mongoose from "node_modules/mongoose/index.js"
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
```

Also tried adding the following lines to package.json:

```
  "type": "module",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
```

Complete error seen below for most of the import cases above:

```
import mongoose, { mongo } from "mongoose";
                   ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'mongo' not found. The requested module 'mongoose' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'mongoose';
const { mongo } = pkg;

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:98:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:143:5)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:165:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

From mongoose index.js file I do not see any other export besides:

```
const mongoose = module.exports = exports = new Mongoose({
  [defaultMongooseSymbol]: true
});
```

Found this github issue [Misleading error that module does not provide export
#32137](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32137) but still not sure how to make this import to work.

Answer (score 0):

This "appears" to be the fix which is the only thing that happened after I took a break.

I had 2 files: B.js and A.js

from A.js:

```
import foo from "./B.js";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
```

I decided to run B.js on it's own to see if it would give me the same error(it had a mongoose import as well), it turn's out there was another different error:

```
foo.pre(save, function(next) {

^ ReferenceError: save is not defined
```

Ok nothing biggy, corrected it and `node B.js` worked fine when running it, hence decided to test with `node A.js`, which worked just fine to my surprise!

This turned out to be **completely counterintuitive**, as the error mentioned initially was not pointing to this.